# TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer!!! while dealing with dates

Tags: python, date, pycharm

I keep getting the following error while performing arithmetics with dates and durations

```
current_date = isodate.parse_date(current_date_str)
period = isodate.parse_duration(period_str)

while:
   current_date += period
   <some code here>
```

in the third line of code I get this Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition
> 2023.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
>     exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)   File "", line 1, in    File
> "D:\project_name\venv\lib\site-packages\isodate\duration.py", line
> 183, in **add**
>     newdt = other.replace(year=newyear, month=newmonth, day=newday) TypeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an
> integer

I tried reinstalling python and all the libraries. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

This most probably is happenening if you are using python 3.10 along with isodate package version 0.6.0. This particular combination leads to the above error.
Updating isodate version to 0.6.1 should resolve the error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).